# Reversed language name

Tags: popularity-contest, underhanded

You should code a piece of code that looks like it outputs the language name but actually outputs the name reversed.

E.g. a Python program should look like it outputs `Python` but should actually output `nohtyP`.

The winner is the answer with the most upvotes in a week!

Comment: Flagged to close as [underhanded questions are no longer welcome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because underhand questions are no longer welcome in this site

Comment: It is such a pity that [tag:underhanded] was made off-topic. The community loves them.

Comment: Could've been interesting if it had said "The characters in the language-name cannot be hard-coded".

Comment: @Adám: Looking at the quality of the answers to this challenge, I can see why we don't like challenges like this on the site any more. Most of the answers are terrible (not even obfuscated at all), and most of the rest are exploiting a loophole in the wording of the question.

Comment: @ais523 I suppose you mean *allow*, not *like*. Well, apart from the loophole (which the OP could address) upvotes (since this is a popularity contest) are supposed to promote the actually clever answers.

Comment: May I suggest adding a rule that prohibits palindromically named languages from participating, or alternatively requires them to add some kind of identifier like a dialect name or a version number?

Comment: I also think you should forbade palindromic languages! @Adám

Comment: From reopen review: this challenge is still off-topic, and although the offtopic subreason given isn't correct (it should be "this challenge is offtopic because it asks for underhanded code"), only a moderator can change the offtopic subreason. So voting to leave as closed.

Comment: Since this is closed: [Keg, 4 bytes](https://tio.run/##y05N///fOzU97v9/AA)

Answer (score 83):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 3 bytes

```php
PHP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P8/wCPg/38A)

It looks like it outputs the language name, but it's actually the letters in reversed order.

Comment: I normally hate underhand questions but this one is brilliant

Comment: Wait, it's reversed? How sure are you...

Comment: The challenge PHP was created for.

Comment: Cannot believe this... I hate Palindromes!

Comment: @KritixiLithos 100%. I pasted the output into a script where I compared it to `'PHP'[::-1]` and it returned `true`.

Comment: OK, so this was funny because it exploited a loophole that OP (a newcomer to PPCG) probably didn't think of, but you shouldn't upvote answer that do not answer the challenge. The answer was supposed to be underhanded. This isn't.

Comment: I don't like that this seems to be considered the standard way to program with PHP. it is more like pure HTML markup. If I type `PHP;` inside the php cli, that is `php -a`, it doesn't print anything but says `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant PHP - assumed 'PHP' in php shell code on line 1`. I think, this answer should be more like `echo PHP;`.

Answer (score 26):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix)

Because Cubix doesn't always need to be indecipherable

```
begin;
print "Cubix" > output;
end@?;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/z8pNT0zz5qroCgzr0RByRkkqKRgp5BfWlJQWmLNlZqX4mBv/f8/AA)

[Watch it running](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=YmVnaW47CnByaW50ICJDdWJpeCIgPiBvdXRwdXQ7CmVuZEA/Ow==&input=Cg==&speed=5)

Comment: This is great!!

Answer (score 24):

## R, 8 bytes

Took me a while to figure this one out, but I think I've solved it!

```
cat("R")
```

Answer (score 20):

## HTML, 11 Bytes

```
&#8238;HTML
```

-4 Bytes hardcoding the unicode character in a html file

## HTML, 12 Bytes

```
&#x202e;HTML
```

The browser do the rest in a html file

```html
&#8238;HTML
```

Comment: Might want to check the [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) tag

Comment: @Mayube now better?

Comment: Yeah that's much better

Answer (score 18):

## C++

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char C = 1;
    std::string CPP;
    for(C++; C++ < 42; C++)
        CPP += "C++";
    std::cout << CPP[C++];
    std::cout << CPP[C++];
    std::cout << CPP[C++];
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pYyxDsIgGIR3nuJSlzaNiRqnQl14ge7GgVCsJBYaCpPx2fEvLu7e8Of@@y6nl2U/aZ3zzjr9TKOBsH6Nwaj5wqyLmJV1dcNeDCT9UAESPY68/Gscu47a1k2Qw/AN7z7Usm056EDgfCquKWwTFdH2qCisfma0TxFCbPhK6PYPCiam4HDg7J3zBw)

Answer (score 14):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 20 bytes

```
"Braingolf"@@@@@@@@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fyQnGVnKAgf//v@bl6yYnJmekAgA)

`@` Prints a character as ASCII, however because `"Braingolf"` pushes the string in order, the last item on the stack is `f`, so the first `@` prints `f`, and so on.

Because of this quirk, the first `Hello, World!` program in Braingolf was actually:

```
"!dlroW ,olleH"@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Sidenote: Braingolf backwards is `Flogniarb`, which might actually be a better language name than Braingolf!

Answer (score 14):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 8 bytes

```
"><>">o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8nOxk7JLt/m/38A)

Fun fact, this actually reverses the name of the language. The name, however, is a palindrome. Which is extra funny to me, because 'paling' (which almost spells the start of 'palindrome') is a kind of eel in Dutch.

Comment: Wait `><>` isn't a palindrome, it's `<><` backwards

Comment: @Mayube instinctively I thought that too and was "Huh, `><>` outputs the stack reversed, why am I getting `><>`".  Then I counted the GT's and LT's...

Comment: but this doesn't work, because it outputs `><>` not `<><`, the goal is to output the language name *reversed*

Comment: @Mayube `><>` reversed is still `><>` ;)

Comment: Oh right yeah I see it now, I had to literally replace `><>` with `121` in the code to understand what you were saying :P

Comment: I am wondering how this got a downvote...

Comment: @steenbergh I countered it. ;)

Comment: Huh... it's funny how it looks like the reverse should be `<><`, but it's `><>`. Geometry!

Answer (score 10):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to cleblanc.*

Specification says nothing about any output on STDERR so...

```c
main(){puts("C");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oLSkWEPJWUnTuvb/fwA)

Comment: Why not use puts("C") to save a couple of bytes.

Comment: First time using C lol. Thanks!

Comment: @Downvoter, please explain.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
“Jelly”U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxwvEOtRw9zQ//8B)

"U" is a meaningless enough atom for "reverse an array" that 99% of programmers will likely assume that this program will output "Jelly". Maybe not so much code-golfers, though.

Comment: This is fairly obvious for even beginner Jelly programs like myself a few weeks ago. (I didn't downvote though).

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Wow, I didn't realize you were a beginner Jelly program! :P

Comment: @Challenger5 Well I'm sorry that I can't engrish :p

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 24 bytes

Outputs on STDERR. This is a simple identity reduction, but APL goes right-to-left!

```apl
{⍺⊣⍞←⍵}/' APL'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdLzE39X/1o95dj7oWP@qd96htwqPerbX66gqOAT7qIAX/QSoA)

---

Alternate, tacit, self-documenting version:

```apl
Print←⍞∘←
Identity←⊣
All←/
Identity∘Print All' APL'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBAFFmXklj9omPOqd96hjBpDB5ZmSmleSWVIJEuxazOWYkwNk6SOEO2aA9SgAJdQVHAN81AE)

---

A.P.L.: An Interactive Approach ([pun intended](http://book-pdf-pkr6.fplys.com/index.php?page=37206)). Let's ask for the three letters and input them in proper order:

```apl
⎕⎕⎕
'A'
'P'
'L'
```

Works because APL evaluates from right to left and thus asks for the rightmost letter first, but we enter the "A" first, etc.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI/6pkIQl7qjOpd6ABD7qAMA)

Answer (score 5):

## J, 3 bytes

Jumping on the language-is-palindrome bandwagon:

```
'J'
```

Comment: Hm… `|.'J'` would be more fitting.

Answer (score 3):

## q, 5 bytes

a one letter language name makes this problem trivial

```
1"q";
```

Output:

```
q
```

Answer (score -1):

## Bash, 10 bytes

```
rev<<<Bash
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyi1zMbGxgnMBgA)

Comment: If you use `sh` instead of `bash` you can save two bytes. Never have I ever suggested switching languages for a program to save two bytes lol

Comment: @Sirens: `sh` doesn't support the `<<<` redirection. `bash` is sometimes renamed to `sh`, but that doesn't change the fact that the language is still Bash.

Comment: I stand corrected: `sh --version: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)`. Kind of nasty that they do that given that sh and bash behave differently.